# How to use an External Display on a MacBook Pro with a cracked built-in-display and without having MacOS installed on it

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, install, hardware

I have a Macbook Pro (A1425) with a broken display.

Because fixing the display is almost as expensive as a new Macbook he bought a new one and gave me the broken one.

Last thing he was doing with it was installing a newer version of MacOS while using an external monitor over HDMI port.

Now it is stuck in the setup because connecting to a display over HDMI now isn't working and I have no idea what to select / where to click to finish the installation because the display is cracked.

How do I to get this laptop to a state where I can use it with an external display again?  Is there any way to activate the video output during setup over HDMI?

Would it be any difference when connection the display over the Thunderbolt port? Is there any live distribution that can be booted from a USB stick which is capable of using external displays over HDMI without having to setup anything first on the built-in screen?

I would be very grateful for any information on how to get this machine back into a usable state without having to fix the built in display.

Comment: Remove the hdd or ssd and do the install as an external drive on a different machine.

Comment: Could this be done on a PC ? I dont have access to any other running Mac/-book

Comment: Don’t think install packages are written to work on pc.

Comment: Me neither.....i was thinking about setting up a VM on my PC and maybe get it done on this way....but i dont know any virtualisationsoftware that is capable of emulating a macbook...and also if sth like that exists....isnt the setup specifically for this kind of hardware inside this macbook or can i use any running macos from a macbook and put it into another macbook with slightly different hardware?

Comment: What happens if you close the lid when the Mac is connected to power and the display?

Comment: well....that did the trick.....dont know why there was no output before but now it works....thanks very much!